# Determining video card compatibility when building mini-ITX desktop

Tags: power-supply, pci-express, mini-itx

I've got a set of salvaged components from a defunct all-in-one PC. 
There's an Intel i7 [7700T](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97122/intel-core-i7-7700t-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html) with matching SO-DIMMs, mini-SATA disk, etc. 
The plan is to build a normal desktop by purchasing a Gigabyte [ga-h110tn](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H110TN-rev-10#sp) motherboard and appropriate power, cooling and case.

However, I couldn't figure out the matching vidocards by myself. There's PCI-e x4 slot on the mobo. But my my country's leading store configurator app insists that I can't use any of the 'normal' videocards (for example, GTX 1650). It says (a) not enough CPU power (b) I don't have PCI-e 6-pin power socket.

In general, is it feasible to build desktops out of laptop components? If so, how can I determine what kind of video card matches my setup?

Comment: Our FAQ explicitly disallows hardware shopping recommendations, but I actually think that this question can be more generalized and should stay open. You wouldn't want to ask about which specific card you can buy for that particular setup, but more general recommendations that could help future readers who don't have exactly the same hardware.

Comment: Yes sir, please. This is obviously not about "what should I buy for my setup" but more about "am I designing my setup right". Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Gigabyte-GA-H110TN/35121

Hopefully this makes it clearer as to what GPUs work on this motherboard. At the end of the day, it is going to be the same GPUs that are often compatible with laptops. If you buy one which might not fit, I suggest you order from a source which has easy return policy, such as Amazon. They generally accept almost anything back.